# Do they have different meanings: a class, class, and classes?

Tags: word-difference

I am going to make up three similar sentences below.

1. > Do you have **a** class today?
2. > Do you have **class** today?
3. > Do you have class**es** today?

I think (1) doesn't make sense because I haven't heard of anyone saying that. (2) is correct because you are talking about the class you are taking right now. (3) is also correct because you are thinking about all the classes you are currently taking. Is my interpretation correct? What is your opinion?

Comment: They are all valid questions and their meanings (at least in AmE) would depend on the context, such as whether the person being asked is a teacher, a college or university student, an elementary school student, etc.

Comment: I thought (1) didn't make sense. When do you say that?

Comment: You say #1 when you want to know if the person has at least one class which they must attend (or conduct) today.   BTW, there are many kinds of classes (academic, exercise, crafts, etc).

Answer (score 1):

All three of your questions are correct

> Do you have **a** class today?

Could be asked to see if the day is free, but might usually be phrased as

> Do you have *any* classes today?

> Do you have **class** today?

Might be used when the class for a specific topic is understood by the speaker and the listener.

Do you have **classes** today?

Is a general question about a variety of topics.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the explanations from the respondents.